# cuda-memcheck Could not start the application (7)

Tags: cuda, gpu

when I use cuda-memcheck ,it's shows

```
./cuda-memcheck  ~/work/local_pc_code/bin/test/test_parm 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Could not start the application (7)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
```

my compile flag is:

```
nvcc -G -g  -Xcompiler -rdynamic -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61  -L /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/ -lcublas -lcudnn -lcudart
```

what's error number 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my testing, `cuda-memcheck` must be run in a directory that your user account has *write* access to, or else it will report the error you indicate.

It seems evident that you are likely doing that:

```
./cuda-memcheck  ...
^^
```

This command invocation (`./`) suggests to me that you are attempting to run `cuda-memcheck` from the directory where it was installed. **This is not typical or expected usage.**  In a typical CUDA install, and assuming you are not root, you would not have write access to the directory that the `cuda-memcheck` executable is located in.

- Make sure you have properly updated your `PATH` environment variable so that you can properly run `cuda-memcheck` from any location.  The instructions for that are [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup).
- change your directory to one that you have write access to.  Presumably you could do e.g.  `cd ~/work/local_pc_code/bin/test/`
- run `cuda-memcheck` from there, e.g. `cuda-memcheck ./test_parm`